# Sort by frequency of rows in associated table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have 2 tables. Products and Stores. A product belongs to a store.

I would like to order stores by the amount of products that belong to them in descending order that were created in the last month. So far I have...

```
Product.where("created_at > ?", 1.month.ago).group_by { |p| p.store }.sort_by { |k,v| v.count }.reverse.map{|a| a[0]}
```

But this is very slow as the group_by function. I should note that I am using PostgreSQL, which has meant that some solutions I have found on the internet have not worked for me.

Comment: Created in the last month? The store? The products? Only count products that were created last month? As always, table definitions and your version of Postgres would be helpful.

Comment: Products that have been created in the last month. My version of Postgres is 9.2.4.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to only count products created in the "last month" (counting back from "now"):

```
SELECT store_id 
FROM   product
WHERE  created_at > now() - interval '1 month'
GROUP  BY store_id 
ORDER  BY count(*) DESC;
```

I didn't even include the `store` table. You only get the `store_id` and no stores without *any* qualifying products. This is as fast as it gets.
An **index** on `created_at` would be instrumental. A multicolumn index on `(created_at, store_id)` would optimize further. More expensive, more specialized, but faster for the query at hand. In pg 9.2+ you could get [index-only scans](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans) out of it.

To include columns of the `store` table as well as stores with 0 qualifying products:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM   store s
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT store_id, count(*) AS ct_prod
   FROM   product
   WHERE  created_at > now() - interval '1 month'
   GROUP  BY store_id
  ) p ON s.store_id = p.store_id
ORDER  BY p.ct_prod DESC NULL LAST, s.store_id;
```

[**`NULLS LAST`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492) is essential to sort rows without any matches last.
I added `s.store_id` as arbitrary tie breaker to get a consistent sort order for stores with the same `ct_prod`.